# Error with simple Acumatica contract soap api call

Tags: api, soap, acumatica

I'm trying to get a simple Acumatica contract-based SOAP API Get() or GetList() call to work and all I'm getting is an error:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: model

See the code below. I first tried the REST API, but couldn't get around different issues (which I'll also probably add in another post).  Any ideas what the error is referring to?

```
using (var soapClient = new ServiceReference1.DefaultSoapClient())
{
    //Log in to Acumatica ERP
    soapClient.Login
    (
        "admin",
        "admin",
        "Company",
        null,
        null
    );

    ServiceReference1.SalesOrder orderToFind = new 
        ServiceReference1.SalesOrder
        {
            CustomerID = new ServiceReference1.StringValue { Value = "2" },
            OrderType = new ServiceReference1.StringValue { Value = "SO" },
            OrderNbr = new ServiceReference1.StringValue { Value = 
                "SO001337" },
        };

        var getOrder = soapClient.Get(orderToFind);

        var getOrders =
            soapClient.GetList(orderToFind);
}
```

Acumatica v17.204.0019.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? I'm hitting the same thing.

Comment: No, sorry. I'm now using the REST API instead.

Answer (score 6):

Just encountered the same error and a little ashamed to admit that solution appeared to be super simply for me: the binding was simply missing `allowCookies="true"` in app.config

Having enabled cookies, error **ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: model** got resolved:

```
<binding name="DefaultSoap" allowCookies="true" />
```

Comment: This bites me every time!

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to add the WSDL as a ServiceReference instead of a WebReference, long story. Another thing to check might be the app.config to make sure it has the correct endpoint, bindings, etc. as per Acumatica documentation.

Comment: Updating the bindings did it for me. I think when I refreshed the service reference the bindings were reset. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When searching for a record, one must always work with a proper variation of the `[FieldType]Search` type. In your case the **orderToFind** object should be declared as follows:

```
ServiceReference1.SalesOrder orderToFind = new ServiceReference1.SalesOrder
{
    OrderType = new ServiceReference1.StringSearch { Value = "SO" },
    OrderNbr = new ServiceReference1.StringSearch { Value = "SO001337" }
};

var getOrder = soapClient.Get(orderToFind);
```

To export orders for the given customer, you should define the **ordersToFind** object as follows:

```
ServiceReference1.SalesOrder ordersToFind = new ServiceReference1.SalesOrder
{
    CustomerID = new ServiceReference1.StringSearch { Value = "2" },
};

var getOrders = soapClient.GetList(orderToFind);
```

Comment: I still get the same error when I change my Get() call to match yours, using StringSearch instead of StringValue, and removing CustomerID when initializing.

Comment: What are name and version of the endpoint you use to export Sales Orders? No errors were on my end with a brand new Acumatica website (build # 17.204.0019.) and Default endpoint of ver. 17.200.001

Comment: I was actually using this url as my wsdl... 
 http://localhost/AcuAmazon172040019/entity/Default/6.00.001?wsdl ... because I couldn't find the R2 path documented anywhere.  So thank you for supplying that.  After changing to http://localhost/AcuAmazon172040019/entity/Default/17.200.001?wsdl as my service reference, though, I still get the same error.

Comment: The full exception starts with (cutoff due to comment length max):

"System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: model\n   at Microsoft.Data.Edm.EdmUtil.CheckArgumentNull[T](T value, String parameterName)\n   at Microsoft.Data.Edm.ExtensionMethods.EntityContainers(IEdmModel model)\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Edm.Helpers.GetEntityType(IEdmModel model, String objectName) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R204-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Edm\\Helpers.cs:line 0\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntity(String expectedEntityType) in ... <etc.>

Comment: It seems that there might be something missing or wrong with access rights or/and endpoint configuration. Could you please create a snapshot of your local test company and attach it to a support case on Acumatica's Partner Portal?

Comment: It's a new installation with the SalesDemo data and the Demo company.

Comment: I'm sorry for saying that, but I'm totally out of ideas... as reported earlier, no errors were on my end with SalesDemo data template on a brand new Acumatica website (build # 17.204.0019) and Default endpoint of ver. 17.200.001